# Auto-size thumbnails in a both left/right justified frame/window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am doing on a webpage for display a large amount of pictures/thumbnails. What I am looking for is to auto-resize the pictures, make each line has fixed height, and the right margin of each line is also equal. Even the images are reformatted when I change the size of window, the above mentioned style is kept.

That is quite similar with what google did when displaying their images search results:

[Google image example](http://www.google.com.sg/search?q=apple&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=zh-CN&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=BrY8T__eA42HrAec843ZBw&biw=1548&bih=849&sei=CLY8T5T9CYSdmQXe-5S2Bw)  (resize your browser window and you may find what I'm trying to say :-) )

Anyone has idea on this would be much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to me there 2-ways, 1)by css 2)by js

1)**CSS**: you can add this in your css, this will resize your thumbnail accordingly.

```
img{max-width:100%;}
```

2)**JS**: Using js you can resize the thumbnails based on the available space and also decide on how many images do you want to show in one row.

Comment: I have basically solve this problem by writing a js to calculate the ratio of row-width and window-width. but thank you anyway,dude :-)

Comment: no problem...well it would be great if you could post your solution here as it would be helpful for others looking for similar solutions. :)